# regular expression not evaluating string correctly

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to split a string based on space except when inside quotes. This is the regex I found online `(\\w+|\".*?\")`. However, when I try to use `std::regex` to split a string, I get only empty strings.

This is the code I have to split:

```cpp
std::regex exp("[^\\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)'");

std::sregex_token_iterator itr(s.begin(), s.end(), exp, -1);
std::sregex_token_iterator end;

for (; itr != end; itr++)
    std::cout << *itr << std::endl;
```

This prints out only `" "` when I pass a string like `"A "B C" 123"`. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: @Taekahn that didn't work. I have already verified that the expression is correct, just my implementation is not working as intended.

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: Believe me, if I weren't told this was the best way to go about it, I wouldn't touch regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [documentation for `std::sregex_token_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator):

> submatch  -   the index of the submatch that should be returned. "0" represents the entire match, and "-1" represents the parts that are not matched (e.g, the stuff between matches).

Since you're passing -1, it means you're printing the parts that *didn't* match, not the parts that matched.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work.

Comment: @RohanS you'll have to be more specific than "didn't work". See https://ideone.com/e2VkF3.

Comment: Nevermind, I had what you did and I got empty strings. I copied and paste what you wrote exactly and now it works. Thanks!